# Error when create installer python project

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

I have a problem when creating an installer for my python project,

I try to execute on cmd this command

```
pynstaller --onefile main.py
```

but before I run it, I have installed all needed package or library for my project,

I use this command

```
pip install face-recognition
pip install playsound
pip install opencv-camera
```

but I have this error
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/038Y7.png)

what should I do to solve this error?

Comment: Check the last line of error, It clearly shows the program unable to open the shapre_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat file.

Comment: what should i do with this error?, i am sorry because i a newby on this

Comment: check that file is available on the path specified in error or not.

Comment: the file does not exists ,should move it file manually?

Comment: yes, you can,  if you have that file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate it into lines
This may work

pip3 install face-recognition

pip3 install playsound

pip3 install opencv-camera

or if that dosen

pip install face-recognition

pip install playsound

pip install opencv-camera

Answer (score 0):

face-recognition requires dlib in the background and dlib is a problematic library to install. I recommend you to use [deepface](https://github.com/serengil/deepface) for face recognition. Because it is mainly based on Tensorflow and Keras and that's why, it is very easy to install.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
models = ['VGG-Face', 'Facenet', 'OpenFace', 'DeepFace', 'DeepID', 'Dlib']
resp = DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", model_name = models[0])
print(resp["verified"])
```

As seen, it wraps the state-of-the-art face recognition models: VGG-Face (University of Oxford), Facenet (Google), OpenFace (Carnegie Mellon University), DeepFace (Facebook), DeepID (The Chienese University of Hong Kong). Besides, it wraps Dlib ResNet model as well.